# Redirect domain in Plesk and Winserver 2008

Tags: redirect, iis, plesk

i got a question. I have a domain: www.example.de.
Now i have a few subsites like www.example.de/intranet, www.example.de/website, www.example.de/something.
Everything works fine, but if my costumers go on www.example.de, it won't work. I want them to get redirected to www.example.de/website, cause this is something like my hompepage. How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possibility to do redirect: 
I wrote an index.php which gets opend.
It contains followning code:

```
<?php
/* Serverside Redirect */
header("Location: /website/"); 

?>
```

So now the site www.example.de gets redirected to www.example.de/website